# SAXParser for JSON when creating DICOM Attributes

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing, saxparser

I am currently working with a project where I receive Dicom XML data, parse the data using SAXParser, store the parsed data as Attributes objects (https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/blob/master/dcm4che-core/src/main/java/org/dcm4che3/data/Attributes.java), and add the Attributes objects to an attributesList.

The parser I use for XML is SAXParser, and I also use SAXParserFactory to create XML parser instances.

After changing the accept header, I now receive the same DICOM data in JSON rather than XML.  Is there a JSON parser and parser factory that I can use for the same purpose?  If so, how should I modify my current code?

My current parsing code:

```
    public void bodyPart(int i, MultipartInputStream partInputStream) throws IOException {
        try {
            partInputStream.readHeaderParams();
            SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            Attributes dicomAttributes = new Attributes();
            parser.parse(new AttributesList.NonClosingInputSteam(partInputStream), new ContentHandlerAdapter(dicomAttributes));
            attributesList.add(dicomAttributes);
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            // This should never happen unless the server returns invalid content. Log and return.
            log.error("Error parsing!", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     private static class NonClosingInputSteam extends FilterInputStream {

    /**
     * Creates a new NonClosingInputStream that wraps another input stream.
     *
     * @param in the input stream to be wrapped
     */
    NonClosingInputSteam(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }


    /**
     * Overrides the default implementation of the input stream's close() method. This implementation
     * does nothing.
     */
    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one by default, so you would have to write your own for this.

But take a look at the specification [here](http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part18/sect_F.2.html)

Based on the Json formatting of DICOM you could see the way the data is being written.

And going further, you could parse based on this to make sure your parsing is fitting with the spec.